# Initializing a ref-to-ptr in a struct after malloc()

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, struct, msvcrt

I'm facing a problem using VC++ and Debug CRT with a DLL in development.

I have a struct like that, holding some references.

```
struct DATA
{
    TA*& a;
    TB*& b;
    TC*& c;
    TD*& d;

    char** chars;
    int num_chars;

private:
    // because:
    // DATA a;
    // DATA b;
    // a = b; // is impossible
    DATA& operator=(const DATA&); // append " = delete;" for C++11

    // Default ctor (private because struct should be manually constructed using malloc)
    DATA(TA*& a, TB*& b, TC*& c, TD*& d)
        : a(a),
          b(b),
          c(c),
          d(d),
          chars(NULL),
          num_chars(0)
    {}
};
```

and construct it like that:

```
DATA*& Get()
{
    static struct DATA *data = (struct DATA*)malloc(sizeof(struct DATA));
    return data;
}
```

now it should hold uninitialized ref-to-ptrs, which I want to init by:

```
void func(TA* a, TB* b, TC* c, TD* d)
{
    Get()->a = a;
    Get()->b = b;
    Get()->c = c;
    Get()->d = d;
    ...
}
```

which works for everything, but ref-to-ptrs..

I'm getting a `INVALID_POINTER_WRITE_FILL_PATTERN_cdcdcdcd` on the first `Get()->a = a;` when I do `!analyze -v -f` using WinDbg (in a remote Kernel Debugging "kd" instance)

Thanks for your help! :)

**Edit: Solution**

Solution is to use the points from the correct answer.

Making the c'tor public is necessary:

```
struct DATA
{
    TA*& a;
    TB*& b;
    TC*& c;
    TD*& d;

    char** chars;
    int num_chars;

    // Default ctor
    DATA(TA*& a, TB*& b, TC*& c, TD*& d)
        : a(a),
          b(b),
          c(c),
          d(d),
          chars(NULL),
          num_chars(0)
    {}

private:
    // because:
    // DATA a;
    // DATA b;
    // a = b; // is impossible
    DATA& operator=(const DATA&); // append " = delete;" for C++11
};
```

then using `placement new`to construct the struct:

```
DATA*& Get(...)
{
    // ... some stuff, overloading, other init-method etc. to init and construct like:
    static struct DATA *data = 
        new(malloc(sizeof(struct DATA))) DATA(...); // At least assign ALL references in the c'tor
    return data;
}
```

then use it and maybe assign everything that's no reference:

```
void func(TA* a, TB* b, TC* c, TD* d)
{
    Get(a, b, c, d);

    Get()->chars = ...
    ...
}
```

free'ing the whole thing needs to be done explicitly by calling the d'tor and `free` , because we use `placement new`:

```
data->~DATA();
free(data);
```

Comment: In C, you don't have reference; in C++, you should't use malloc. choose your language.

Comment: just down-voting, for what? it's a question I was facing, thereis an excerpt to get an idea how it's working and I pointed out a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `malloc()` returns uninitialized memory. C++ objects need to be constructed. The way to get an object into uninitialized memory is to use placement new (this code also adds clean-up):

```
#include <new>
DATA*& Get()
{
    static DATA *data = new(malloc(sizeof(struct DATA))) DATA(...);
    static std::unique_ptr<DATA, void(*)(DATA*)> clean(data,
                                                [](DATA* d){
                                                    d->~DATA();
                                                    free(data);
                                                });

    return data;
}
```

There is no way in C++ to reseat references, i.e., they need to be set during construction. Personally, I wouldn't use `malloc()` but rather a suitable allocation anyway:

```
    static DATA* data(new DATA(...));
```

... or, as Jarod42 pointed out, actually

```
    static DATA data(...);
    return &data;
```

Comment: Just curious, how would you release that memory (the one with placement new)?

Comment: or no allocation at all: `static DATA data(..); static DATA* dataptr = &data;`.

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, there are many ways. If the use of `malloc()` is required, though, it is interesting to clean up, too...

Comment: this may be useful to clean up when using `placement new` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918791/how-to-properly-free-the-memory-allocated-by-placement-new

Comment: @DominikP: I prefer my use of `std::unique_ptr<...>()` but, yes, getting rid of these guys isn't entirely straight forward.

Comment: what happens if `malloc` returns `NULL` in this code?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: You'll get undefined behavior. Admittedly, I just addressed how to construct an object in the memory. Checking it is there can be done but it gets a bit more involved.

Comment: My number is 42, not 43. And it misses `static` for `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare references without initializing them. Your `struct` has **no** default constructor, since you explicitly declare a non-default constructor. Just allocating `malloc` is not sufficient to create a valid `DATA` object, as it is a [non-POD type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Data_Structures).

Just go ahead and try declaring a real default constructor (i.e., `DATA() {}`), and you'll see that this won't work because of the reference members. If you want to use `malloc` to allocate non-POD objects, you'll have to use a [placement `new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).