# Actually what return type has a new?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, malloc, new-operator

I read [this](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=40) and [this](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/home/papers/c++-new.html) article and to my astonishment I found that the operator has a `void*` return type.

```
void* operator new (size_t size)
{
 void *p=malloc(size); 
 if (p==0) // did malloc succeed?
  throw std::bad_alloc(); // ANSI/ISO compliant behavior
 return p;
}
```

But from other hand, we know, that new returns an object instead void pointer. How it is possible ?

Ok, let's make a little change to code above

```
void* _new (size_t size)
{
 void *p=malloc(size); 
 if (p==0) // did malloc succeed?
  throw std::bad_alloc(); // ANSI/ISO compliant behavior
 return p;
}
```

Now, will the compiler will prevent warnings concerned with casting void* of another type?

Comment: How would the "new" signature look like when returning an object?

Comment: These are custom implementations and may probably be wrong?

Comment: @VAndrei The OP probably means `new()` should return a pointer to the newly created class.

Comment: This is a custom implementation of new, and not how it's actually implemented in C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yep. But in that case you can't write a function signature to return a pointer to any type of class. So that's why void* is used and the cast is done by the compiler without a warning.

Comment: @VAndrei Despite you make it a template function.

Comment: You have mistaken an expression containing the keyword `new` for an invocation of `operator new`.

Comment: Related: [How to properly free the memory allocated by placement new?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8918791/845092)

Comment: A new-expression has special semantics. When the type is supplied, that is the type of the returned pointer (despite the return type being `void*` for the global `operator new`).

Answer (score 4):

The type of a new-expression is a pointer to the type being created. So the type of `new int` is `int*`.

`operator new` is a function called by a new-expression to allocate memory to store the object(s) it's creating. It returns `void*` because there are not yet any objects in that memory. The new-expression then creates one or more objects in that memory before yielding a correctly-typed pointer to those objects.

`operator new` (and the corresponding `operator delete`) can also be called directly to allocate raw memory. For example, the default allocator `std::allocator` used by the standard library's containers does this.

Comment: And what about casting void* to custom object type ?

Comment: @user2846015: I don't know what that's got to do with anything. The new-expression will do that conversion in order to give you the correctly typed pointer. If you call `operator new` directly (not via a new-expression), there's no object there, just raw memory, so you shouldn't cast it.

Comment: I think this conversation would be made more confusing if we also covered placement `new`.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes it would, so I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You've mistaken an expression containing the keyword `new` for an invocation of `operator new`.

That `operator new` returns `void*` has nothing to do with what a `new`-expression evaluates to!

Consider `operator new` to be part of the "inner mechanics" of the overall `new`ing process.