# What is the underlying implementation of placement new?

Tags: c++, gcc, placement-new

```cpp
T *p = ::operator new(sizeof(T));
new (p) T;
```

I wonder how that syntax is working, given that placement new is declared as:

```cpp
void* operator new(std::size_t, void*)
```

The second argument `void*` seems point to the storage of the object, so how does C++ connect the `new (p) T` to the `void*`?

In gcc libsupc++ the implementation is simply:

```cpp
// Default placement versions of operator new.
_GLIBCXX_NODISCARD inline void* operator new(std::size_t, void* __p) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
{ return __p; }

_GLIBCXX_NODISCARD inline void* operator new[](std::size_t, void* __p) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
{ return __p; }
```

Is the compiler responsible for translating the syntax `new(*T) T` to the calling of a placement `operator new`?

Comment: placement new doesn't really do anything itself.  What it does do is tell the compiler to construct a `T` at the place the provide `T*` points to.  This is required as there is no way for you as a programmer to call an objects constructor.

Comment: It's just a normal operator overload. Well, *almost* normal. `new T` will invoke `operator new(size_t)`. Then you can add any kind of arguments you want. For example you can create an `operator new(size_t, int)` which can be invoked like `new (123) T`. You can even have multiple arguments.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918791/how-to-properly-free-the-memory-allocated-by-placement-new/8918942#8918942

Comment: Note that the syntax is more general. You can put anything in `(...)` after `new`, and it will get passed to `operator new(size,...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it compiler's responsibility to translate the syntax new(*T) T to
> the calling of a placement operator new?

Yes, exactly.

Placement `new` can not be implemented as a library function, it needs special handling from the compiler anyway. The actual implementation that you saw in the libsupc++ source code can be misleading here, as most of the crucial properties of a placement new call are not reflected by that implementation.

Comment: *placement* new doesn't require any special handling by the compiler. It works exactly the same as any other new expression. People just get confused because we virtually never pass parameters to `new`

Comment: @MooingDuck What I meant was that `operator new` cannot be implemented as a library function *in general*. I did not mean to imply that placement `new` is a special case among the various `new` variants here.

Comment: Pedantically, `operator new` is almost always implemented as a library function in general :P. But you are correct that the `new` expression can't, since that also calls the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Using the regular `new` expression does two things: it calls the function `operator new` which allocates memory (but does NOT construct), and then it calls the constructor at that location, to create the object at that memory.

For placement new, the `operator new(std::size_t, void*)` is a no-op, and just returns the pointer that was passed in, and then the compiler calls the constructor at that location, to create the object at that memory.

```
//normal version                   calls these two functions
MyClass* pMemory = new MyClass;    void* pMemory = operator new(sizeof(MyClass));
                                   MyClass::MyClass(pMemory); //pseudo-syntax
```

You can also make your own custom `new` methods, which also work with this same general mechanism.

```
void* operator new(std::size_t, const char* name) {
    return get_memory_by_name(name);
}

const char* allocation_name = "complex_float";
std::complex<float>* c = new(allocation_name) std::complex<float>{};
```